# Android TableRow with two lines

Tags: android

I need to implement a table in an Android App organized as follows:

< Fixed Header with the names of the columns >

< Scrollable Table with rows >

Each row should contain two lines:

- the first line contains a long text description
- the second line contains the values of the columns whose names are in the header

For example

```
Date    |    Hour    | Price
----------------------------
Special offer for this reason
11/01       10:00        30
----------------------------
Special offer for that reason
12/01       9:00         20
```

Actually, the number of columns is greater than three so I cannot add the string description on the same line as the other values. The values correspond to entries in a DB: each entry has a description + other values.

I was able to obtain the fixed header and the scrollable table using two nested TableLayouts. I could obtain the same effect by nesting a third TableLayout inside of the TableRows.

I would like to ask you whether there is a simpler way to obtain the same effect.

Comment: This can be done easily with a listview.

Comment: That corresponds to my current implementation. My problem is that header column names (seven) are not aligned, sometimes they are not even displayed from the third upward. There is clearly a problem with my implementation, but I cannot find a single example.